GeoServer's "Cloud optimized GeoTIFF" plugin taking much time to publish larger files from Azure blob storage
I am currently facing challenges with setting up a Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF (COG) store via Azure blob storage in GeoServer for larger files.
When I try to publish a layer from a store it becomes endless loading like this for larger files > 1.2GB, and it is working fine for small files such as 450 MB (as I tested with)

And This is what I get in the terminal.

Version details:
GeoServer version : 2.22.0. (because for latest version of GeoServer and cog-azure-plugin is not even able to create store for azure-blob)
JVM Version : 11.0.24 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
cog-plugin : geoserver-2.22-SNAPSHOT-cog-plugin
